# Select query for get title and url of node

Tags: database

I need to query the database directly using php. I need to limit my query to nodes created in the current year. I know that the node table contains the date the node was created in the 'created' column and that this contains a date as a timestamp.

I am not sure how to get the current year and express it as a range of timestamps and return only nodes that were created between the two timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make any tricks like that to compare a timestamp to the current year.

You can obtain the **year of the timestamp** by using the PHP [date](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php) function:

```
date('Y', 1394010573)
```

will return

```
2014
```

You can obtain the **current year** by using the same function but without mentionning any timestamp (it will take the current date by default):

```
date('Y');
```

Knowing this, you can easily limit your query.